# A newbie question in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :  
    QMainWindow(parent),  
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)  
{  
    ui->setupUi(this);  
}
```

In this section of code,  after `:` what does

```
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
```

mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is actually a C++ question.  What you're looking at are called [initialization lists](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html).  The `QMainWindow(parent)` calls that constructor for `MainWindow`'s superclass (`QMainWindow`) and `ui(new Ui::MainWindow)` constructs `ui` member.

Comment: so this is only used in construct function? or can be used in any kind of fucntions?

Comment: .. but in all kinds of constructors, including _copy constructors_.

Answer (score 9):

By way of further explanation, observe that the class generated by the user interface compiler is also called (in this case) `MainWindow`, but it belongs to the namespace `Ui`, so its full name is `Ui::MainWindow`.  This is emphatically not the same as the `MainWindow` class that inherits from `QMainWindow`.  However, the `QMainWindow`-derived class has a member pointer (called `ui`) to a `Ui::MainWindow`, which is initialized in the constructor, as explained above.  Have a look at the uic-generated file `ui_mainwindow.h` to see how all the pieces fit together.  Note also that the members of `Ui::MainWindow` are all public and therefore fully accessible within `MainWindow`.

An alternative design is to merge the identity of the two `MainWindow` classes using multiple inheritance, deriving your own `MainWindow` from both `QMainWindow` and `Ui::MainWindow`.  However, the code generated by current version of *QtCreator* follows the composition pattern rather than the inheritance pattern.

Comment: +1 - this answer was a good reminder that Ui::MainWindow is a product of the MOC and isn't actually declared in MainWindow.h - the declaration there that looks like...

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

...is actually a stub class to speed up compilation.

Answer (score 5):

These two lines are the so-called **initialization list** and are executed at "creation" time of each instance of this class. Each class inheriting another should contain a call to the superclass' constructor in this list.

You could also write:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :  
    QMainWindow(parent)
{  
    ui = new Ui::MainWindow();
    ui->setupUi(this);  
}
```

which one could find better readable. But using an initialization list is slightly faster and is being optimized by the compiler. Note that these lists can only be used in constructors and you cannot call any functions of the object - because it doesn't "live" yet. But you may set the value of some attributes and refer to them in following statements (to avoid code redundancy for example), like in the following example:

```
#define DEFAULT_VALUE 1.0

class MyClass {

public:
    MyClass() :
        value1(DEFAULT_VALUE),
        value2(value1)
    {
    }

    MyClass(qreal value) :
        value1(value),
        value2(value1)
    {
    }

private:
    qreal value1;
    qreal value2;
};
```

Note that most compilers give you a warning if the order of the members in your initialization list doesn't match the order in the class definition.